# generate XML attributes instead of elements

Tags: xml, jaxb

I'm using the `@XmlRootElement` annotation along with `@XmlElement` to generate an xml output in my Spring MVC application. I have the following classes:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Chart
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Connection> connections;
    //..................

    @XmlElement(name = "connection")
    public List<Connection> getConnections()
    {
        return this.connections;
    }

    //..................
}

public class Connection
{
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public String getFrom()
    {
        return this.from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from)
    {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo()
    {
        return this.to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to)
    {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an xml output like this:

```xml
<chart>
    <id>a1</id>
    <name>chart1</name>
    <connection>
        <from>a1</from>
        <to>a2</to>
    </connection>
    ....
</chart>
```

However, I need to have the xml formatted in this way:

```xml
<chart>
    <id>a1</id>
    <name>chart1</name>
    <connection from="a1" to="a2"></connection>
    ....
</chart>
```

How can I configure the annotations in order to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2):

Use `@XmlAttribute` on the specific elements of `Connection` that you want to treat as attributes.

```java
public class Connection
{
    private String from;
    private String to;

    public String getFrom()
    {
        return this.from;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setFrom(String from)
    {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo()
    {
        return this.to;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setTo(String to)
    {
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - The `@XmlType` annotation is not required for this use case:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the answer accordingly.